# Why is my CUDA Toolkit not being detected when running Python code in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: pytorch, gpu, conda, sublimetext3

So I want to run python code in sublime text with my GPU, but I cant get it done.

If I run this code:

```
import torch


def main():
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        device = torch.device("cuda")
        print("CUDA is available. Using GPU:",
              torch.cuda.get_device_name(device))
    else:
        print("CUDA is not available. Switching to CPU.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

it will output: `CUDA is not available. Switching to CPU.`

This is the build system I used in sublime:

```
  "cmd": ["C:\\Users\\Edi\\miniconda3\\Scripts\\conda.exe", "run", "-n", "Env_CUDA", "python", "-u", "$file"],
  "selector": "source.python",
  "shell": true
}
```

`Env_CUDA` is the environment that I used in which I done the following commands:

```
conda install cudatoolkit=11.8`

conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.8 -c pytorch -c conda-forge
```

Also the environment was done with python 3.10. I have a `gtx 1660 S`, I installed CUDA toolkit version 10 install type exe (network)

I really don't know any other detail I should also add so fell free to ask and sorry in advance :)